# multiple forms handled by one script php

Tags: php, multiple-forms

I try to create an order page on php. I have created a form which stores data into the database. The form number is based on the user and it is created dynamic.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_num']))
{
    $number=$_POST['sky'];

    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
    {
            $item = $_SESSION['item'];

            echo $item;
            $rec_query = "SELECT * FROM ylika";
            $rec_result= mysql_query($rec_query) or die("my eroors");

            echo '<form action="user_order_form.php" method="POST">';
            echo '<html>';
            while($row_rec = mysql_fetch_array($rec_result))
            {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="yliko[]" value='.$row_rec['onoma'].'> '.$row_rec['onoma'].'';
                echo '<br>';
            }
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ORDER">';
            echo '</form>';

    }

}
?>
```

So I have many forms and 1 script to handle them. If I submit 1 form then it applies the data to the database but the other forms dissapear. This is the second php 'handler'.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $max_id = "SELECT MAX(id_order) FROM id_of_orders";
    $x=mysql_query($max_id) or die("my eroors");
    $id= mysql_fetch_array($x);
    $xyz = $id['MAX(id_order)'];

    $item = $_SESSION['item'];
    $temp = $_POST['yliko'];
    $temp2 = implode(",", $temp);
    $inserts = ("INSERT INTO orders (order_id,product,ulika) VALUES ('$xyz' , '$item','$temp2')");
    $inc_prod=("UPDATE proion SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE proion.onomasia='$item'");
    mysql_query($inserts) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($inc_prod) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

I want to submit all the forms. Should I try to create one submit button for all of the forms or is there a way to handle all of them separately ?

Comment: Is that `echo '<html>';` supposed to be there? Seems an odd place (ie before lots of code...)

Comment: nop, i forgot it, my bad. still no error by that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many submit forms, but simply define one big `<form>` with all of them, then you will not lose any information.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_num']))
{
    $number=$_POST['sky'];

    echo '<form action="user_order_form.php" method="POST">';
    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
    {
            $item = $_SESSION['item'];

            echo $item;
            $rec_query = "SELECT * FROM ylika";
            $rec_result= mysql_query($rec_query) or die("my eroors");

            echo '<html>';
            while($row_rec = mysql_fetch_array($rec_result))
            {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="yliko[]" value='.$row_rec['onoma'].'> '.$row_rec['onoma'].'';
                echo '<br>';
            }
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ORDER">';

    }
    echo '</form>';

}
?>
```

now you can also add the ~$i~ identifier to input names, so you can easily distinguish which is which.

Comment: still after i submit one form it goes to start again

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "goes to the start again"? lejlot's post should be good to go. The form is called before the loop, then the loop occurs, then the form is closed. Submitting the form should submit everything provided.

Comment: I tried this and after i created 2-3 forms ,then I pressed submit for 1, it ran the script and reset back to menu. what i want is to submit all the forms

Comment: should i create something like a mutex to wait for all the submits and after run the store script ?

Comment: ok i think i got it. i should delete the inside submit inputs and create an input for the outside form.